# TFS 2012 - building a web application project that references a class library in another team project

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm having trouble getting TFS 2012 to build a web application project that references a class library project that lives in another team project.

Here's how the projects look in source control:

```
- $/
  - TP1
    - Development
      - Source
        - WebAppProject
  - TP2
    - Development
      - Source
        - ClassLibraryProject1
```

I simplified this structure for the purposes of this example - there are other solutions and projects in each team project.  Assume that `TP2` contains code that is intended to be used by other projects, not just `TP1`.

The solution that contains `WebAppProject` also contains `ClassLibraryProject1`. It was added from `TP1` using **Add Existing Project**. `WebAppProject` also has a project reference to `ClassLibraryProject1`.

I am working on a team build that builds the projects across `TP1` and `TP2`.  I created the build definition in `TP2` and set up the following workspaces:

- $/TP1/Development build agent folder gets set to $(SourceDir)\TP1\Development
- $/TP2/Development build agent folder gets set to $(SourceDir)

TFS can't build `WebAppProject`, and the error actually makes sense ...

TFS is attempting to resolve the reference to `ClassLibraryProject1` using the project reference from `WebAppProject`; e.g.: `..\..\..\TP2\Development\Source\ClassLibrary1`, however, that path obviously won't exist on the build server.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to set up a artifact repository such as NuGet (at the sophisticated end of the scale), or even a commonly accessible network folder (at very basic end of the scale).

Build and output the shared library to the artifact repository using a separate build job/process.

Reference it in consuming projects via the artifact repository and some mechanism to 'get latest' (e.g. NuGet get, for NuGet; xcopy/robocopy batch script, for shared network directory).

Adding the shared project to your solution directly can easily lead to a world of pain, e.g. if someone accidentally or unknowingly makes changes to the shared project from within your solution.

Comment: Thanks chamila_c, would you be able to point me to an example of using NuGet as an artifact repository?

Comment: Keep in mind that this isn't a lightweight way of doing it, but certainly quite robust - [Setting up a local NuGet gallery](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/contribute/setting-up-a-local-gallery)